How to show only one class of the clusters in Google Earth Engine where NDVI gt (0.2)
How to show only one class of the clusters in Google Earth Engine where NDVI gt (0.2).
Suppose we have the following codes for unsupervised classification. My goal is to  mask out other classes (clusters) and only map one of the clusters (where NDVI gt (0.2))in my results.
https://code.earthengine.google.com/e1d2ad869f29a627466cbed1546f53bb
